# Influence of Interactions

Tags: machine-learning, interaction, boosting

I am simulating the following model on R:

$X_1, X_2\sim \mathcal{U}(-1,1)$

$$Y = b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 +b_{12}X_1X_2 + \epsilon$$

$\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

I am running code on R to investigate the *influence* of the interactive terms on the model for Gradient Boosting Machines (using `gbm` package):

```
n<-1000 # number of observations

# generate some covariate variables training data
x1<-runif(n,-1,1)
x2<-runif(n,-1,1)
# choose some parameters
b0<-0
b1<-1
b2<-1
b12<-2
sigma<-1

# calculate linear predictor
logodds<-b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+b12*x1*x2+rnorm(n,0,sigma)

# calculate probabilities
p<-exp(logodds)/(1+exp(logodds))

# simulate response variable
y<-rbinom(n,1,p)

data<-data.frame(y,x1,x2,x1*x2)

model<-gbm(y~x1*x2,data=data)

summary(model)
```

`summary(model)` produces a bar chart of the influence of each variable and interactive variable:

[image: Influence of each variable on the model]

It is clear that the $X_1X_2$ has no influence at all on the model - but it is unclear why, as I have explicitly programmed the model to include the interactive terms.

Given that the interactive term is literally part of the model, I'm assuming that it should have significant influence.

Would this be a flaw of GBM? Or am I missing something crucial or made an incorrect assumption?

EDIT: Regarding what `gbm` means by *Relative Influence*, `help(summary.gbm)` states:

*For distribution="gaussian" this returns exactly the reduction of squared error attributable to each variable. For other loss functions this returns the reduction attributable to each variable in sum of squared error in predicting the gradient on each iteration. It describes the relative influence of each variable in reducing the loss function. See the references below for exact details on the computation.*

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how "relative influence" is defined by `gbm`?  Evidently, `gbm` is flexible enough to "know" that apart from random errors, variation in `y` is completely explained by variations in  `x1` and `x2`.  I wonder whether there may be some miscommunication between you and `gbm`: what do you intend by including `x1*x2` in your construction of `data`?

Comment: I have edited my question to include how *Relative Influence* is defined by ```gbm``` - my understanding is that (rouguhly speaking) how much is the error affected when removing a particular term

Comment: With regards to what I intend by including ```x1*x2``` - I am intentionally adding an interactive term in the simulation to test whether its influence can be detected - given that the interactive term is *literally* part of the model, I'm assuming that it should have significant influence

Comment: Including the `x1*x2` variable in `data` doesn't do anything in `gbm`, though: that's why I wonder what you are supposing.  It begins to sound like you want to define `data <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,x12=x1*x2)` and invoke your fitting procedure as `gbm(y~x1+x2+x12,data=data)`.

Comment: I have done what you have said and it has worked! Thank you for your help

Comment: Is that a meaningful result, though?  That calculation assumes you can vary `x1*x2` independently of `x1` and `x2`, but obviously you cannot.

Comment: I see - I've just taken a quick look at ```help(summary.gbm)``` and it doesn't seem to accomodate such cases. Perhaps it's better to use Partial Dependence Plots or Friedman's H-Statistic?

Comment: I don't know, because it isn't clear what you're really trying to accomplish.  It looks like `gbm` is doing the right thing and giving useful information: to wit, after accounting for `x1` and `x2`, their product `x1*x2` is irrelevant.  At the same time, it appears you are seeking something more akin to the *regression coefficient* for the interaction.  Those are different concepts, so only one (if either) can correctly answer whatever your underlying statistical question might be.